# my external php doesn't understand input's name attribute value which is declared in ReactJS's render()

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs, forms

I am trying to make a ReactJS application which needs to communicate to PHP.

I could to use nodeJS but I chose PHP because I learned it some years ago and don't want to forget it.

So, what should happen in my app:

When user submits submit button(which is also rendered in render() ),instead of redirecting to php file, app will send ajax request to the external php file. PHP file should get input's value.

but php shows such warnings in console when I remove if(isset()) from the file.

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: search in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ReactStudy\travelReduxApp\public\server\itemList.php** on line **13**

These are my codes

index.js

```
import ajaxRequest from './ajax';
console.log(store);
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('AppName').classList.add('visible');
},300);

class App extends React.Component{
   submitForm = (e)=>{
     e.preventDefault();
     //console.log(this.refs.search.value);
     const value= this.refs.search.value;
     ajaxRequest(e,value);
   }
   render(){
      return(
          <div>
            <section id="Search">
                <form  id="Search" data-object="form" method="GET" onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                    <input ref={'search'} placeholder="search country, attraction names" type="text" name="search"/>
                    <button type="submit">SEARCH</button>
                </form>
            </section>
            <ItemList/>
        </div>
    )
 }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
 document.getElementById('App')
)
```

ajax.js

```
export default function ajaxRequest(e,value){
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
switch(e.type){
    case 'submit':
        xhr.open('get','//localhost:80/ReactStudy/travelReduxApp/public/server/search.php?'+value,true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data){
            switch(xhr.status){
                case 200:
                    const text = xhr.responseText;
                    console.log(text);
            }
        }

  }
xhr.send();
}
```

search.php

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* ');
  /*shows warning without isset*/
  /*$form = $_GET["search"];
  echo $form;*/

 /*with isset shows not found*/
 if(isset($_GET["search"])){
   $form = $_GET["search"];
   echo $form;
  }else{
  echo "not found";
 }
 ?>
```

could please someone find or teach me why my php can't find input tag with name attribute's value search?

the input tag is already rendered into the document when php is called. What am I missing?

I am using webpack and bundle.js is included on the bottom of the  tag.

edited my code. I am using GET in my code and I don't know why I wrote POST here. So, forget it. I am using $_GET in my php code. Pardon me.

Comment: AJAX doesn't automatically pass the values on. The fact you've got a name attribute is irrelevant when you send data via ajax. You have to specifically tell the AJAX call what data you want to send. It doesn't just submit the whole form like a normal postback.

Comment: `xhr.open('get', ...)`, `$_POST["search"]`… ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Also `if(isset($_POST["search"])){
   $form = $_GET["search"];` makes no sense - you're asking if the variable is set in POST but then looking for a GET variable. Make up your mind. Your AJAX request uses GET so that might also be part of the issue.

Comment: @ADyson Oh, I don't know why I did $_POST in this thread. In real, I am using $_GET and result is the same.

Comment: @deceze my mistake in this thread. I am using $_GET in real and doesn't work. Pardon me. I don't know why I wrote POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing your Ajax is sending is this.refs.search.value - not the name "search" / not url encoded / not multi-part encoded. Indeed, you seem to have invented your own encoding system.

Try:

```
xhr.open('get','//localhost:80/ReactStudy/travelReduxApp/public/server/search.php?search=' + value,true);
```

in Ajax.js

Comment: Thanks. Solved the issue. Pardon me again.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* ');
  /*shows warning without isset*/
  /*$form = $_GET["search"];
  echo $form;*/

 /*with isset shows not found*/
 if(isset($_POST["search"])){
   $form = $_GET["search"];
   echo $form;
  }else{
  echo "not found";`ghd`
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Some explanation of your answer is needed. What's changed from the original code?

Comment: I can't see how this would help? Apart from introducing what appears to be a syntax error after the echo, you haven't changed anything from the original version in the first edit of the question, and you seemingly haven't noticed the mistake in it, despite the various existing comments. If you think your code will help somehow, you'd need to explain in order for people to find it useful.